# Routing traffic around packet loss and high ping areas?

Tags: internet, proxy

I am trying to find out how to change the route my traffic takes in order to avoid servers which are causing me packet loss. I have traced the route and I know the servers addresses, but the owners (Level 3 communications) will not do anything to help. Any resolutions for this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a VPN to another point and route your traffic via that.  (If its HTTP traffic, yes, you can use a proxy server to do this instead).   There is nothing a typical "end user" can do to instruct ISP's how to route packets unless they are using a dynamic routing protocol (in practice "BGP"), unless they have multiple connections and they can route traffic out different connections to bypass issues.

Comment: Do I set up the proxy through my modem

Comment: Not on a consumer grade router.  You would set the proxy up on each browser, and, of-course, you need a proxy server outside your network you can work with.  In Firefox its Edit->Preferences->Advanced->Settings.  Other browsers are similar.